# Duplicating Serial Com Port to Spy on Communication between device and software

Tags: serial-port

I am attempting to spy on the serial com port connecting between a software on a PC and a device connected to a RS-232 serial com port. My thinking is that I could duplicate the com port connection to the device and simply read out the duplicated version. Is this feasible and can this be done?